# who to load JSON object into Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

My DataTable function in body tag html, if that possible i don't want use AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test_table').dataTable( {
        "aaData": JSON_obj,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "name"},
            {"mDataProp": "chance"},
            {"mDataProp": "multi"},
            {"mDataProp": "frequency"}
        ]
    }); 
});
```

JSON_obj(form mongodb):

```
{"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8480":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8480"},"chance":8,"frequency":600,"id":3,"multi":100,"name":"Jerboa","xp_reward":1},"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8481":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8481"},"chance":50,"frequency":600,"id":2,"multi":10,"name":"Partridge","xp_reward":1},"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8482":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8482"},"chance":100,"frequency":20,"id":1,"multi":1,"name":"Dabb","xp_reward":1}}
```

Can you help me?
and excuse my bad English!

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: see this link : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/21769

Comment: i need to load JSON_obj into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8480":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8480"},"chance":8,"frequency":600,"id":3,"multi":100,"name":"Jerboa","xp_reward":1},"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8481":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8481"},"chance":50,"frequency":600,"id":2,"multi":10,"name":"Partridge","xp_reward":1},"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8482":{"_id":{"$id":"52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8482"},"chance":100,"frequency":20,"id":1,"multi":1,"name":"Dabb","xp_reward":1}}';

$("#attr").dataTable().fnAddData(data["52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8480"]);
$("#attr").dataTable().fnAddData(data["52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8481"]);
$("#attr").dataTable().fnAddData(data["52efa4c17bc16b98d47b8482"]);
```

Comment: Sory but i don't get it, how i can use this in datatable?

Comment: $("#attr") is your dataTable. The function fnAddData is a function on the datatable and the object you pass inn corresponds to the columns.

Comment: http://live.datatables.net/ohOh/4/edit?js,output